# tsconfig error when setting module to ES2017

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, lit-element

Following documentation for LitElement my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
  {   
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "ES2017",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true
      },
    "include": [
        "src/*"
    ]
}
```

I see an error saying

> TS6046: Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs',
>   'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'esnext'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in the LitElement docs](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/574). There error tells you what's wrong. [Typescript `module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) does not support `ES2017` as a value. You should change it to `es2015` or `esnext`.

Comment: That worked :) I'm surprised such a large project got something so basic wrong in their docs. Will raise an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding the "lib" array to your compiler options as shown below?. Also change all occurences of es from **ES** to **es**

```
  {   
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "es2017",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
                  "es2017",
                  "dom"
                ]
      },
    "include": [
        "src/*"
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that did not fix the error.